# testu01 installation problems on mac OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, random

I installed testu01 on my mac (OS El Capitan). I want to compile one of the examples using gcc, code below. But I get the following error, below. Did anybody run TestU01 on x86_64 successfully? Any other suggestions?

```
MacBook-Pro-2:examples Joan$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -O3 -o birth1 birth1.c -I/Users/TestU01/TestU01-1.2.3/include -I/Users/TestU01/TestU01-1.2.3/mylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_smarsa_BirthdaySpacings", referenced from:
      _main in birth1-c99705.o
  "_ulcg_CreateLCG", referenced from:
      _main in birth1-c99705.o
  "_ulcg_DeleteGen", referenced from:
      _main in birth1-c99705.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You've not specified the name of the unit test library that defines the `ulcg_*` names on the command line (you probably need to add `-lunittest` for some appropriate name; you might need to add `-L/Users/TestU01/TestU01-1.2.3/lib` to the command line before the `-l` option).  The `smarsa_BirthdaySpacings` name looks more like it might be part of the `birth1.c` code than the unit test library.  Is it a typo in `birth1.c` or did you need to link something from the `mylib` directory into the executable (as well as including headers from it).

Comment: While we can all wield Google reasonably effectively, it would be better if you included a link to where you obtained the `testu01` code for your system.  Was it installed by HomeBrew or one of the other installers, or did you collect the code yourself and compile and then install it somewhere?

Comment: The software can be downloaded from http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html.  Note that the README file contains the information: _Then the small example birth1.c in directory examples can be compiled with
the C compiler: `gcc birth1.c -o birth1 -ltestu01 -lprobdist -lmylib -lm`_  Which at least is different from what you show.  On a Mac, the `-lm` is not needed (though it's not harmful either) — macOS takes the sensible view that the main maths library should be available by default.

Comment: hi Jonathan, 
I have testu01 from http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html,
I am using Source files (zip archive) from the webiste.

gcc birth1.c -o birth1 -ltestu01 -lprobdist -lmylib -lm  alone will give you an error birth1.c:2:10: fatal error: 'unif01.h' file not found
#include "unif01.h" because 'unif01.h' is in fact in /include directory

Comment: for the libraries in TestU01-1.2.3 folder there is no /lib folder, only /mylib.
'ulcg' header files are in /textu01 directory so should be linked

Comment: IT IS RESOLVED
Solution was that the package was not properly installed and was linking to non existent libraries. Initial error 86_x64 made me think if there was a compatibility issue as original TestU01 package is quite old. But no, it is working just fine. 
Thanks for your comments Jonathan